# What is this Google Apps popout menu called?

Tags: menu, terminology, google, bootstrap

What is this menu called in UX/UI parlance?

[image]

I want to implement this type of menu in my UI (ASP.NET MVC 5). My default styling is done with Bootstrap 3+.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What's it called?**

I'm not sure if a canonical name exists. But here are some terms that help describe it...

- It is a type of **menu**. ([Google Material Design: Menus](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html))
- In iOS and Bootstrap parlance it is a type of **Popover**. [(iOS Developer Library: Popovers)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html)
- Google specifically calls it an **App Launcher**. [(Google Support: Use the Google Bar)](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?hl=en)

**How do I implement it?**

If you wanted to build your own, I would use the Bootstrap Popover component and populate it with a grid of divs containing large icons paired with labels.

You could use the following recreation of the App Launcher as a starting point:
[Google App Launcher Code Pen](https://codepen.io/nhalstead/pen/abNzZmX) by Manar Kamel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be referenced by the picture it makes. We call it either the Google Apps Chiclets or the Google Apps Waffle.

Comment: However, it is formally called the Google Apps Launcher. Not very eloquent.

Comment: Can you give more details here please? A source, ideally.

Comment: Could you point to a source in print?